# How to deal with master tables in asp. Net Mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on an Asp. NET MVC(Angular JS) project which is targeted for 500 users, we are not using entity framework as we thought it is not an option for such a large number of users and costs performance. we are creating Data Access Layer separately. I have multiple master tables around 40 like inventory, category, error type..etc.

My Question is for retrieving each transaction record we may need to refer 10 to 15 master tables. SQL joins will make the query complex and will definitely hit at least 10 master tables which costs performance?

Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Would you like to get data from all master table?

Comment: have you tested any of these assumptions - all EF does is generate queries that perform pretty well under normal circumstances. The type of application you outline would suggest that your 500 (concurrent?) users won't download the entire DB to the client would they?

Comment: i can say Average of 10 to 15 master tables per record , i haven't tested these assumption, just assuming whether EF will cope with such number of users.

Answer (score 0):

SQL JOINS should not add that much overhead if the foreign keys are indexed correctly. I have queries with more than 20 joins and takes less than a second to run.

If the queries are getting too complex you may want to re-consider your database design. If this is not an option, it would be worth looking at indexing the right fields.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest go with D-Normalization. You need to create indexed views. They are good in performance.